# SQL Table return number of items with review number ID

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table which has reviews saved like this....

[image: SQL Database Example]

I am looking to return the amount of reviews listed for a certain ID number.  The table itself is called gg_reviews

I know this is real simple but for some reason its baffling me, can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, you just need to `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY`.  The `GROUP BY` field should be the unique value for each page.

```
SELECT count(*) as TotalReview, ID  -- change ID to the unique id for the page
FROM gg_reviews
GROUP BY ID  -- change ID to the unique id for the page
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which ID you want to count reviews for, but provided that it's the page_id:

```
SELECT page_id, COUNT(*) as totalReviews
FROM gg_reviews
GROUP BY page_id
```

Answer (score 0):

kk.. can't find there a way to see where you store the id.. but i would "suggest" the following:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(ID) as views FROM gg_reviews GROUP BY ID
```